# Ajax url parameters not appended correctly - Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to make a POST request to my rails using jquery.

**my values for ajax call**

```
$('input[type=submit]').unbind().bind('click', function() {
    // extract category id from hidden field
    var category = $("#category_id").val();
    var category_id = category.split("=>").pop(-1);
    category_id = category_id.replace("}","");
    // extract question id from hidden field
    var question = $("#question_id").val();
    var question_id = question.split("=>").pop(-1);
    question_id = question_id.replace("}","");

    // init new array to pass choices
    var checked = [];
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
      var whole_id = $(this).attr("id");
      var id = whole_id.split("_").pop(-1);
      checked.push(id);
    });

    var answers = JSON.stringify(checked);
    console.log(checked);
    retrieve(answers,category_id,question_id);
  });
```

**ajax call**

```
function retrieve(answers,category,question) {

 $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      url: "/categories/" + category + "/questions/" + question + "/retrieve",
      data: answers,
      success: function(data) {

      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        alert("The error code is: " + xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
  };
```

**routing**

```
resources :categories do
    get '/random_question', action: 'random_question', controller: 'categories', as: 'random_question'

    resources :questions do
      post '/retrieve', to: 'questions#retrieve'

      resources :choices, only: [:index]
    end
  end
```

**controller**

```
def retrieve
    @category = Category.find_by(params[:category_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to category_questions_url, notice: 'success'  }
      format.json {
        render json: {
          message: "success"
          }
        }
    end
  end
```

i get a 404 error(not found) and the url is like this

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/%222%22/questions 404 (Not Found)
```

which is wrong.

also in network tab of chrome dev tools i get this

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in QuestionsController#index

Couldn't find Category with 'id'="2"
```

Comment: Is http://localhost:3000/categories/2/questions working?

Try changing the url to:
      url: "/categories/" + parseInt(category) + "/questions/" + question + "/retrieve",

Comment: i tried, it returns NaN for the parseInt. I found that for some reason the url became `/categories/"2"/questions/"1"/retrieve` why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed that your sending category_id and question_id as a string, not a number. Instead of the tricky hacks do:

```
// extract category id from hidden field
var category = $("#category_id").val();
var category_id = parseInt(category);
// extract question id from hidden field
var question = $("#question_id").val();
var question_id = parseInt(question);
```

And it should be golden. Tried your way in the console and it still returning a string, there's your problem

Comment: i am afraid this does not work because i get this in the hidden input value field. `{:value=>1}` thats why i do string stuff.but you are right its a string.

Answer (score 1):

As user TomD originally suggested is that i get strings and i need to convert them to integers.

But the real problem was that the hidden input value attribute had `:value=>1` instead of just `1`

after doing the following on my hidden input fields everything worked like TomD said to do.

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag :category_id,params[:category_id], value: params[:category_id] %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag :question_id,params[:id], value: params[:id] %>
```